# Wie antwortet man auf "frohes neues Jahr", um "and to you too" zu sagen?

Tags: preposition

Meine Versuche:

> 1. Frohes neues Jahr auch **an dich**
> 2. Frohes neues Jahr auch **an dir**
> 3. Frohes neues Jahr auch **zu dir**

Im Google findet man Ergebnisse für alle drei Formen. Antwort 1. hat die meisten Ergebnisse.

**Edit**: hier geht es nicht um wie man "and to you" auf Deutsch gleichwertig ausdrückt, sondern um die (un)mögliche Verwendung von "an/zu" + Pronomen auf eine der vorgeschlagenen Weisen.

Comment: Wenn du es in einer relativ normalen Konversation benutzen willst, würde ich einfach "Ebenfalls." sagen. Du musst den Satz nicht unbedingt wiederholen. Das käme auch dem englischen "same to you" gleich. Nur zur Klärung.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Auch Dir ein frohes neues Jahr.

Bei Wünschen dieser Art bleiben häufig einige Satzteile implizit.
Der ursprüngliche Wunsch "Frohes neues Jahr" steht eigentlich für
"*Ich wünsche Dir ein* frohes neues Jahr".
Die Antwort darauf ist "*Ich wünsche* auch Dir ein frohes neues Jahr",
und da Subjekt und Verb wieder implizit bleiben, ergibt sich
"Auch Dir ein frohes neues Jahr".
(Im ersten Satz entfallen auch das Dativ-Objekt und (optional) der Artikel,
aber weil im zweiten Satz "auch" davor steht, müssen diese nun stehenbleiben.)

Die Reihenfolge der Satzglieder steht, wie meist im Deutschen,
nicht völlig fest:

> Dir auch ein frohes neues Jahr.

oder

> Ein frohes neues Jahr auch dir.

sind ebenfalls möglich.

Answer (score 3):

Die Antworten 1-3 sind IMHO grammatikalisch falsch. Man sagt nicht *Ein frohes* *neues Jahr zu* oder *an Dich*. Uwe's Antwort gibt den korrekten Ausdruck. Man könnte auch sagen *Ein frohes neues Jahr auch für Dich*.

Comment: Grammatisch falsch sind sie nicht. Wenn, dann semantisch falsch (2) und unidiomatisch (1,3)

Answer (score 1):

Es genügt "Danke, Dir/Ihnen auch", ja nach Bekanntheits-/Höflichkeitsgrad.

---

Um auf den entsprechenden EDIT der Frage zu antworten: Nein, *an* und *zu* können in diesem Zusammenhang nicht verwendet werden. *für dich* wäre möglich.

Comment: Ja klar, aber das beantwortet die im Post gestellte Frage nicht.

Comment: 1. Im Post wird keine Frage gestellt. 2. Die Frage in der Überschrift lautet kurzgefasst, was ist das korrekte Äquivalent zu "and to you too" als Antwort auf "Frohes neues Jahr". Und ein gängiges Äquivalent ist eben "Danke, Dir auch". Weitere Fragen kann ich weder der Überschrift noch dem Text entnehmen.

Comment: Im Post nicht, im Titel schon. Du brauchst nicht so pingelig zu sein. Und es geht um ob man "an/zu + Pronomen" verwenden darf, nicht um alternative Antwortsarten, die ich übrigens schon kenne. Wenn das unidiomatisch, falsch or was auch immer ist, nun sag so. Besser?

Comment: Wenn Du andere Antworten willst, stell die richtigen Fragen ;-) Deine Frage lautet "Wie antwortet man auf “frohes neues Jahr”, um “and to you too” zu sagen?". Darauf ist meine Antwort eine korrekte mögliche Lösung und beantwortet damit auch die Frage. Das ist übrigens die einzige Frage, die Du gestellt hast. Wenn Du wissen willst, ob man die genannten Pronomina verwenden darf, dann frag das auch - und ich bin nicht pingelig, ich beantworte Fragen.

Comment: Ich habe die Frage bearbeitet, um das klarer zu machen.

Comment: Und ich habe meine Antwort bearbeitet, um die erweiterte Frage zu beantworten.